# Automatic resizing for 'non-retina' image versions

Tags: xcode

I'm looking for a solution that can save me from maintaining two versions of the same image, one for Retina displays (aka @2x), one another for non-Retina displays. My goal is to maintain the "2x" images only, and have some 'magic tool' resize all of them with a single click or even better upon building in XCode. Like "set it and forget it".

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "magic tool" can just be you not including other images. They will be scaled automatically (though not perfectly) for older models without retina display.

Comment: Should I mark them with the "@2x" anyway?

Comment: No. If you go this route, do **not** use the `@2x` suffix.

Comment: But doing this way if I drag them in the XCode 4 designer they are **huge**. There is something I don't understand. I'm sorry.

Comment: They will appear twice as large since the resolution is 2x.

Comment: And this doesn't work good for me. I need the integrated interface builder to work as expected and the images to appear as 1x even if their resolution is 2x. And I can **only** achieve this by creating, **manually**, two versions of the images (one 1x, one 2x), and dragging the 1x one onto the designer window. Question is: how to make the 1x image generation automatic? Just using a 2x one (without '2x' in the filename) breaks the Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes in this case you MUST have a 1x and 2x. Also look at my answer because I think it might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just want to downscale them, you can have Xcode automatically generate all non-retina images during the build process. This example script uses "sips" because that is preinstalled on Macs.

#### The Script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Downsamples all retina ...@2x.png images.

echo "Downsampling retina images..."

dir=$(pwd)
find "$dir" -name "*@2x.png" | while read image; do

    outfile=$(dirname "$image")/$(basename "$image" @2x.png).png

    if [ "$image" -nt "$outfile" ]; then
        basename "$outfile"

        width=$(sips -g "pixelWidth" "$image" | awk 'FNR>1 {print $2}')
        height=$(sips -g "pixelHeight" "$image" | awk 'FNR>1 {print $2}')
        sips -z $(($height / 2)) $(($width / 2)) "$image" --out "$outfile"

        test "$outfile" -nt "$image" || exit 1
    fi
done
```

#### Automatic Execution

- Create a new "Aggregate Target", name it "Downsample images".
- Add a "Run script" phase to this target that runs the script.
- Add the "Downsample images" target as a "Target Dependency" in your app target(s).

#### Notes

Remember to still add your 1x images to the Xcode project. Depending on your needs you might also want to:

- exclude certain files from conversion
- add the generated files to your .gitignore file
- use ImageMagick's "[convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)" instead of "sips". (sips seems to fail for some indexed PNGs.)
- run [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)

ImageMagick comes with a "[compare](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/)" command if you want to check the downsampled versions.

Comment: Hm, interesting option, I didn't think about it! :)

Comment: Works great, using it in XCode 6.  You have to install it a little differently, it's easier now.

Answer (score 8):

This is quite an old thread, but I stumbled onto it, so I can elaborate on maintaining more than one size automatically.

Performance-wise, I'm not sure using the automatic downscaling is a wise idea, as it has to be done in real-time, but it should work on simpler cases.

Now, to convert these `@2x`images automatically, a simple bash script should do the trick. **l4u**'s solution works, but for guys with simpler needs who do not want to install `guard`, this also works (you still need to install ImageMagick, though) :

```
for f in $(find . -name '*@2x.png'); do
    echo "Converting $f..."
    convert "$f" -resize '50%' "$(dirname $f)/$(basename -s '@2x.png' $f).png"
done
```

Comment: This solution doesn't keep original color space.

Answer (score 3):

It's trivial:

1. Only include @2x images in your project.
2. Make sure those images have the @2x suffix.

The system will automatically downscale for non-retina devices.

The only exception is if you are doing manual, low level Core Graphics drawing.  You need to adjust the scale if so.  99.9% though, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Don't you mean -hd? If it is a -hd image wouldn't it downscale that if it is a non-retina device?

Comment: Incorrect: Quote:"Apple uses the ”@2x” suffix, but cocos2d doesn't use that extension because of some incompatibilities. Instead, cocos2d has its own suffix: ”-hd”."
Link: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3ahow_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d

Comment: Nowhere does the original poster mention Cocos2d.  My answer is for loading images in the bundle via Cocoa.

Comment: Problem is: Interface Builder. Am I forced not to use it?

Comment: You can use or not use interface builder.  The system will do the right thing.

Comment: -1: only including @2x images clashes with Apple guidelines, and will probably cause memory issues on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

u can simply use only *@2x.png images for your app. 
but you must set the content mode = UIViewContentModeAspectfit for the imageviews,
then it will automatically fix the image to the releventimageviews.

Comment: I think you are confusing the point of UIView's contentMode.  content mode is about how to scale content into a view, since there is no guarantee that they are ever the same size.  Has nothing to do with retina displays.

Answer (score 0):

Or what you can also do is: Have only the @2x images in your app's bundle then on the first launch. Take all the @2x photos and downsize them by 1/2 and store them in the documents directory. Then when you need your photos for a UIImageView say, just grab them for the documents directory and set it to your UIImageView **using code and not Interface Builder!**

I was wondering this a few weeks ago too and I realized that this is pretty much the only way to really do what you are looking for!

Comment: This is unnecessary.  The system will automatically downsize @2x images for you.

Comment: Really? So if it is not a retina device, it will downsize automatically for me and put the image into wherever it should be?

Answer (score 0):

I've created http://l4u.github.com/blog/2012/04/02/resizing-retina-images-with-guard-for-cocos2d-iphone-slash-cocos2d-x/ to generate non-hd images on the fly when -hd images are created/updated. It uses guard, guard-shell and imagemagick

You can replace -hd with @2x.

Answer (score 0):

Try Resource Helper on the Mac App Store 
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/resourcehelper/id521474600

It costs $10.49 but it's worth it. Checks if your images are Retina friendly (i.e. even numbered width/height dimensions) and generates the corresponding image inline. Also handles creation of ~ipad and @2x~ipad graphics as needed.

EDIT: I am not affiliated with the authors of Resource Helper.

Answer (score 0):

What I've been doing for our applications is asking our designer to export everything twice as big as it needs to be, then running a little [node script to resize the images](https://github.com/balderdashy/deretina) (anything named @2x in the directory where you run the script).  Presently, we're just running the script when every time we deploy (it's idempotent), but it could easily be incorporated into forever -w or some other file-change-watching library like [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard).

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I found a use for @nschum's script - I noticed though that it doesn't round numbers for the @1x images if it's dividing an odd number. If I recall correctly this introduces a performance hit; wound up slightly revising it as below. Alters the awk call slightly to do the division there and round it accordingly, and won't re-create @1x images if one already exists (you might want to remove that, dunno).

At this point we've pretty much hit the point where non-retina isn't a big deal (the iPad 2 is all that remains...? The original Mini too, I guess), so meh. Throwing it up for posterity.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Downsamples all retina ...@2x.png images.

dir=$(pwd)
echo "Downsampling Retina images..."

find "$dir" -name "*@2x.png" | while read image; do
    outfile=$(dirname "$image")/$(basename "$image" @2x.png).png

    if [ "$image" -nt "$outfile" ] && [ ! -f "$outfile" ]; then
        if [[ $(dirname "$image") =~ "Images.xcassets" ]]; then
            echo "Skipping Image XCode Assets directory"
        else
            basename "$outfile"
            width=$(sips -g "pixelWidth" "$image" | awk 'FNR>1 {printf "%.0f\n", $2/2}')
            height=$(sips -g "pixelHeight" "$image" | awk 'FNR>1 {printf "%.0f\n", $2/2}')
            sips -z "$height" "$width" "$image" --out "$outfile"
            test "$outfile" -nt "$image" || exit 1
        fi
    fi
done

echo "Finished downsampling Retina images"
```